# Negative lookahead regex for apache mod header cookies - keep certain cookies

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, cookies, regex-lookarounds

Trying to modify an apache request header directive, I need to use a negative lookahead regex to keep only certain cookies.

Test string

```
someCookie=someValue; anotherCookie=yada61; cookieToKeep1=myValue; cookieToKeep2=myValue2; lastCookie=yada1
```

Trying to remove all cookies but `cookieToKeep1` and `cookieToKeep2`.

I can use the below regex but only matches the name and not the = and cookie value.

```
\\b((?!cookieToKeep1=\[^;\]*|cookieToKeep2=\[^;\]*).)\\S+
```

Apache directive that I tried:

```
RequestHeader edit Cookie "(\b((?!cookieToKeep1=[^;]*|cookieToKeep2=[^;]*).)\S+)" ""
```

Comment: Well, you [get what you need](https://regex101.com/r/TbwE8U/1), don't you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - i've only got the cookie name and not the value.

Comment: @anubhava   RequestHeader edit Cookie "(\b((?!cookieToKeep1=[^;]*|cookieToKeep2=[^;]*).)\S+)" ""

Comment: Try `\b((?:cookieToKeep1|cookieToKeep2)=[^;]*)|(?:(?!(?:cookieToKeep1|cookieToKeep2)=).)+`, see  https://regex101.com/r/TbwE8U/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this directive to remove all cookies except `cookieToKeep1` and `cookieToKeep2`:

```sh
RequestHeader edit* Cookie "\b(?!(?:cookieToKeep1|cookieToKeep2)=)([^;=]+=[^;]*(?:; *|$))" ""
```

[`RequestHeader edit*` performs multiple search and replacements.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader)

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TbwE8U/4)